# Using Arrays to build a multiple choice quiz in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to create a Ruby program where users can take a multiple choice test.

I have a file for each test, where the questions and answers are stored like this:

```
Q;Who is the President of the USA?
A;Obama;0 
A;Trump;1 
A;Bush;0
Q;When did Iceland gain independence?
A;1944;1
A;1901;0
A;1974;0
```

Q signifies a question and A signifies an answer option. 
Value 1 is assigned to correct answers and 0 to incorrect answers.

I've converted the lines into arrays like so:

```
IO.foreach("#{test_name}.txt") do |line|
  line.chomp! 
  exam = line.split(";") 
end
```

My issue is that I want to display a Question
and then the Answer options UNTIL I get to the next Question

I've been using `puts` inside the IO like so:

```
IO.foreach("#{test_name}.txt") do |line|
  line.chomp!
  exam = line.split(";") 
puts exam[1] + "\n" 
  end
end
```

But of course that just returns the entire list from the file.

Essentially, I want the output to look like this:

```
    Who is the President of the USA?
    1. Obama
    2. Trump
    3. Bush
Please enter answer

    When did Iceland gain independence?
    1. 1944
    2. 1901
    3. 1974
Please enter answer
```

Basically, I want to know if there is a method for reading a file like this, preferably numbering the answer options?

Comment: You need lot more logic in your code. Ruby does not have magic helpers to help you. You might want to start reading http://ruby-doc.org/. Other thing to note is your question is very vague and seems like you asking people for the whole solution.

Comment: Thank you @hans  I was trying to make the question as clear as possible, but I understand that I might be off. I am very new to Ruby and stack overflow, but I've been trying to figure my own way out of this using The Book of Ruby, Stack Overflow etc. but so far I haven't been able to find anything. I just want to know if there is a way to read files/display arrays like this, or if I am completely off track.

Comment: You have to find a suitable representation for the quiz data using Ruby objects. That could be custom classes or a combination of hashes and arrays. Then you can read the file and create / fill your objects accordingly. Finally you can loop through your questions and collect answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do things in Ruby. This is one among many solutions, quickly made, just to put you on the right track. It lacks tests, for example to verify that the content of lines conforms to expectations.

```
class Question
    def initialize(p_text)
        @choices = []
        @text    = p_text
    end

    def add_answer(p_choice, p_validity)
        @choices << [p_choice, p_validity]
    end

    def ask
        valid_number = nil
        puts
        puts @text
        @choices.each_with_index do | choice_and_validity, i |
            choice, validity = choice_and_validity
            valid_number     = i if validity
            puts "#{i + 1}. #{choice}"
        end

        print 'Please enter answer', ' > '
        answer = gets.chomp.to_i - 1

        unless answer == valid_number
            puts 'Wrong answer.'
            ask
        end
    end
end

@questions = []

IO.foreach('input.txt') do | line |
    case line[0]
    when 'Q'
        code, text = line.chomp.split(';')
        @question  = Question.new(text)
        @questions << @question
    when 'A'
        code, choice, validity = line.chomp.split(';')
        @question.add_answer(choice, validity.strip == '1' ? true : false)
    else
        puts "Wrong code #{line[0]}"
    end
end

p @questions

@questions.each{ | question | question.ask }
```

or

```
class Question
    attr_reader :choices, :text

    def initialize(p_text)
        @choices = []
        @text    = p_text
    end

    def add_answer(p_choice, p_validity)
        @choices << [p_choice, p_validity]
    end
end

@questions = []

IO.foreach('input.txt') do | line |
    code, text, validity = line.chomp.split(';')

    case code
    when 'Q'
        @question  = Question.new(text)
        @questions << @question
    when 'A'
        @question.add_answer(text, validity.strip == '1' ? true : false)
    else
        puts "Wrong code #{code}"
    end
end

p @questions

@questions.each do | question |
    answer       = nil
    valid_number = question.choices.index{ | item | item.last } # find the item [x, true]

    until answer == valid_number
        puts
        puts question.text
        question.choices.each_with_index do | choice, i |
            puts "#{i + 1}. #{choice.first}"
        end

        print 'Please enter answer > '
        answer = gets.chomp.to_i - 1

        puts 'Wrong answer.' unless answer == valid_number
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely put me on the right path!